# module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'extractOne'

Tags: python

Im trying to use for the first time the fuzzywuzzy library, but its giving to me an error with the following code

```
    import fuzzywuzzy as fuzz


def join_fuzzy(df1, df2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=1): 
    s = df2[key2].tolist()
    match_dict = {}
    for i in df1[key1]:
        match = fuzz.extractOne(i, s)
        if match[1] >= threshold:
            match_dict[i] = match[0]
    df_output = df1.merge(df2, left_on=key1, right_on=key2, how='left')
    df_output[key2] = df_output[key1].map(match_dict)
    return df_output

df=join_fuzzy(categoriasdf, descripciones, 'Empresas', 'Razón Social Empresa')
```

I dont understand the reason, cause extractOne is writed as expected. Any idea?

Comment: `fuzz.process.extractOne()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extractOne` is available from `fuzzywuzzy.process`.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process
# ...
process.extractOne(i, s)
```